# How can one customize the name of the PCH file in a C++/WinRT component?

Tags: c++-winrt

When using the `Windows Runtime Component (C++/WinRT)` template in Visual Studio there is a generated file called `module.g.cpp` which uses a hardcoded pre-compiled header filename: `pch.h`. Is there a way to customize this if I want to use a different name? If not, could this be done in a future release of `cppwinrt.exe`?

I also came across a [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209467/hard-coded-pch-name-in-winrt-xaml) mentioning a similar limitation but for the XAML compiler. Perhaps both tools should provide a switch for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next release of cppwinrt.exe has a new "-pch" switch that does exactly that. It will be available in a preview SDK. Integrating this into the project templates would be a new feature request, and if it's important to you, put that request into some feedback on VS and/or the C++/WinRT VSIX.

Comment: Thanks. Really looking forward to some advancements in the tooling around C++/WinRT alongside its XAML support. Copying files manually and having to "Exclude from build" the source files in Solution Explorer (because they do not update) under MIDL and XAML files is not the best developer experience. Still, all this stuff is awesome!